# How do I display query records at different places on my webpage?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

**UPDATE:**
 I used the following query:

```
$act1 = $dbh->prepare("(SELECT Title, start_date FROM service_o ORDER BY start_date DESC limit 2) UNION (SELECT Title, Start_Date FROM research_o ORDER BY start_date DESC limit 2) UNION (SELECT Title, Start_Date FROM intern_o ORDER BY start_date DESC limit 2) UNION (SELECT Title, Start_Date FROM participate_o ORDER BY start_date DESC limit 2)");

$act1->execute();
$act1->fetchAll();
$result = $act1->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Is it absolutely necessary to use var_dump? Moreover, I get an undefined offset error on using this:

```
echo $result[0]['Title']
```

Comment: I made a small mistake in my code, remove the single line that has this `$act1->fetchAll();` but keep this line `$result = $act1->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: The purpose of var_dump is to verify the contents of the result set.  You can simply remove it.

Comment: Thank you, the change made it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `execute`, then `fetchAll` to return all your results as an array.

```
$act1 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT  Title, start_date FROM table1 ORDER BY start_date DESC limit 2 
    UNION
    SELECT  Title, Start_Date FROM research_o ORDER BY table2 DESC limit 2 
    UNION
    SELECT  Title, Start_Date FROM intern_o ORDER BY table3 DESC limit 2 
    UNION
    SELECT  Title, Start_Date FROM participate_o ORDER BY table4 DESC limit 2 ");

$act1->execute();
$result = $act1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

var_dump($result);
```

Your array will be in a structure that looks like this:

```
$result = [
 '0' => [ 'Title' => 'some title', 'Start_Date' => '2009-10-15'],
 '1' => [ 'Title' => 'some title', 'Start_Date' => '2009-10-15'],
 '2' => [ 'Title' => 'some title', 'Start_Date' => '2009-10-15'],
 '3' => [ 'Title' => 'some title', 'Start_Date' => '2009-10-15'],
 '4' => [ 'Title' => 'some title', 'Start_Date' => '2009-10-15'],
 '5' => [ 'Title' => 'some title', 'Start_Date' => '2009-10-15'],
 '6' => [ 'Title' => 'some title', 'Start_Date' => '2009-10-15'],
 '7' => [ 'Title' => 'some title', 'Start_Date' => '2009-10-15'],
];
```

This means you could access each element of the array in your panels by calling:

```
echo $result[0]['Title'] . ' - ' . $result[0]['Start_Date'];
```

Or if you want to loop through them and display all at once:

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo '<div class="panel">' . $row['Title'] . ' - ' . $row['Start_Date'] . '</div>';
}
```

Read more on `execute` here which shows to fetch data from a query: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php

> Executes a query that has been previously prepared using the mysqli_prepare() function.

Comment: I updated the details to highlight the problem I am facing with your approach.